# Running a function when the routine is loaded through appload (autoLISP)

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, I have a routine and I want that, when someone loads it into autocad, a pop up appears on the screen with a little explaining of what it does. I know how to do the popup, but I have no idea on how to make it run specifically when the routine is loaded, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very easily achieved: in short, you would simply include an `alert` expression outside of any `defun` expression within the AutoLISP file, such that the `alert` expression is evaluated immediately when the content of the AutoLISP file is evaluated on load.

For example:

```lisp
(defun c:test ( )
    (princ "\nThis is the main function.")
    (princ)
)

(alert "Type \"test\" to run the main function.") ;; This will be displayed on load
(princ)
```

When the above AutoLISP file is loaded, the interpreter will read the content of the AutoLISP file and will immediately evaluate all AutoLISP expressions contained therein.

As a result, the `defun` expression will be evaluated first and will define a function `c:test` which may then be executed at the AutoCAD command line as a result of the `c:` prefix.

The `alert` expression will then be evaluated and will display a message box to the user, as desired.

Finally, the closing `(princ)` expression will be evaluated and will return a null symbol to the command line so as to achieve a *'clean load'*. If the final `(princ)` expression were to be omitted, the `alert` expression would return a value of `nil` to the command line.